# How to append a file(copied from aws s3 bucket) to another file in Linux,

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cat

I want to copy file from S3 bucket and I need to append the file to another file. I want to done in single command. aws s3 cp s3://sample/test.txt /home/user/test.txt
this command is overwriting the existing file. If i use "cat >>" it was giving error. TIA.

Comment: You can't with just shell commands.  Why does it have to be a single command?

Comment: Write the two commands in a shell script and execute that as one command, or run both commands on the same command line e.g. cmd1;cmd2 or cmd1 && cmd2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy to standard output:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/foo.txt -
```

Therefore, you could append it to a file:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/foo.txt - >>appended_file
```

See: *Downloading an S3 object as a local file stream* at the bottom of: [cp — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)